# What would be the SQL query for this?

Tags: sql, oracle

List the name of all clients who have viewed a property based on the UML graph

```
SELECT [C-NAME]
    FROM [CLIENT]
    JOIN  [PROPERTY]
    ON CLIENT.CLIENTID = PROPERTY.PROPERTYID
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a real question?

Comment: What do you mean? I asked what would be the sql query to list the name of all clients who have viewed a property based on the uml graph

Comment: SQL and relational algebra (if possible)  query to list the name of all clients who have viewed a property based on the uml graph

Comment: What did you try. What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior?

Comment: School assignment? If we do it for you, you'll not learn much. Check out `JOIN`'s.

Comment: This seems to be a school assignment.

Comment: So my join query is not correct in this case?

Comment: Why do you need to ask? Can't you TEST your query to see if it is correct?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood that UML model you can't, View-Appointment needs ClientID and PropertyID adding.

Then you can do, to give all clients that have an appointment (obviously adding a `WHERE` on the date column will give you future/past appointments):

```
select [C-Name] from [Client] inner join [View-Appointment] on Client.ClientID = View-Appointment.ClientID;
```

If you want property details in the query then you need another inner join:

```
inner join Property on Property.PropertyID = View-Appointment.PropertyID
```

Comment: Do you mean this as an Oracle answer? What is [C-Name] here?

Comment: @mathguy C-Name is just a field name from the supplied UML.  No idea what weird naming convention thinks that's a good name! :D  As for the SQL, its just plain SQL would apply to most RDBMS wouldn't it?

Comment: What I meant is, in Oracle at least, column names enclosed in square brackets will raise a syntax error. But I see your point. (Of course, in Oracle you can't have dash (-) in non-quoted object names either.)